# Changing target framework of class library

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-standard, class-library, .net-standard-2.1

I have a class library that currently targets .Net Standard 2.1. When I created the project, I had set it to 2.1 not necessarily for a particular reason. I was being overzealous.

Now I want to use it in a Xamarin project but I keep getting an error stating that Xamarin project can’t use a 2.1 project because Xamarin project targets .Net Standard 2.0.

So I changed the target framework to 2.0 in my class library’s project file and recompiled it but Xamarin project is still rejecting it for the same reason.

Is there anything else I need to do to change the target framework of a class library project?

Comment: Check what dll path xamarin is using: it might be using the 2.1 deploy folder

Comment: No, it’s a NuGet package. I made sure that I pointed to the new NuGet package I generated after switching to .Net Standard 2.0

Comment: Did you so a clean build.  There still may be some obj files that did not get compiled with new Net.  Look at the dates in the project obj folder to see if everything compiled.  Also check the bin release and debug folder to see if both were recompiled.

Comment: Yes, cleaning up the project did the trick. I have a follow up question though. Do I need to install this NuGet package to all three projects i.e. main, Android and iOS?

Comment: Apparently I do need to install it to all three projects. First, I installed it to the main project only and used a simple util function that came with my NuGet package. Even though I could call it, when I ran the app, I got a binding error. I then installed my NuGet package to Android and iOS projects as well. I then recompiled and ran the app and it worked like a charm!